# Can you extract data from a struct in elixir in a pipe?

Tags: elixir

I have a function that hashes an input string into a list with numbers, and places it in a struct.

```
def hash_input(input) do
  hexList = :crypto.hash(:md5, input)
        |> :binary.bin_to_list
  %Identicon.Image{hex: hexList}
end
```

I want to write a test that ensures that each element in hexList is an integer, so I came up with this:

```
test "Does hashing produce a 16 space large array with numbers? " do
  input = Identicon.hash_input("løsdjflksfj")
  %Identicon.Image{hex: numbers} = input
  assert Enum.all?(numbers, &is_integer/1) == true
```

I tried to use the pipe operator (for my own learning sake) to write the test, but I am unable to extract the hex attribute in the pipe with pattern matching.

```
test "Does hashing produce a 16 space large array with numbers? With pipe " do
  assert Identicon.hash_input("løsdjflksfj")
        |> %Identicon.Image{hex: numbers} = 'i want the input to the pipe operator to go here' # How do you extract the hex-field?
        |> Enum.all?(&is_integer/1) == true
```

Is what I am trying to accomplish at all possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really pipe like that, but what you could do is pipe into `Map.get` to get `:hex` and then pipe that into `Enum.all?`.

```rb
"løsdjflksfj"
|> Identicon.hash_input()
|> Map.get(:hex)
|> Enum.all?(&is_integer/1)
```

If you really want to use pattern matching in your pipe, notice that what you need to do is ensure that what gets passed along the pipe is just the value you want to pass (in your case `numbers`).

So, you could also use an anonymous function that takes in the result of `Identicon.hash_input/1` and produces the value of `:hex`:

```rb
"løsdjflksfj"
|> Identicon.hash_input()
|> (fn %{hex: numbers} -> numbers end).()
|> Enum.all?(&is_integer/1)
```

Notice the `.()` right after the anonymous function. That means that it should be invoked right there.

But I would say the `Map.get` approach is more idiomatic.